# short code is not working in in custom wordpress theme it's only working in default theme

Tags: shortcode

```
<?php /*template name: my template*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[STORE-LOCATOR]'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I use this code in my template, and I also use my short code. But this short code is working only in default theme not in custom theme so please let me know how to use shortcode in custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the function defining the shortcode in your custom theme too.

Look for the [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) function in your default theme and add the `add_shortcode` line and it's callback function to your theme's `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're calling `get_header` **twice** - and the **footer not at all**.

Secondly, where/how did you add your shortcode?

In order to create a new shortcode `[short_code_name]` and use it, you have to do the following:

```
add_shortcode( 'short_code_name', 'short_code_func' );
function short_code_func() {
    return "That's my shortcode. Yay!";
} // function short_code_func
```

You could do this in your theme's `functions.php` file, for instance.